# How my JS file path in node.js should be?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, ejs

I want to show one `.ejs` file when my server in `node.js` is running. This is my code in `app.js`:

```
app.get('/imc',function(req,res){
   res.render("imc/calculaImc");
})
```

So far, everything is okay, the file is showing up.
However, i don't know how to pass the path of the JS file inside of `.ejs` file:

```
<script src= "test.js"> </ script>
```

This is my folder: [image: This is my folder]

Comment: Anything you want to serve up will either have to be exposed in your app.js as a static asset or you will need to put it in a public folder.

Comment: Right, how can i do theese things? I'm starting at JS

Comment: Since you are short on details while using `app.get` I assume it is from expressJS. Then http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to export the folder as a static asset in your `app.js` file and then use it in the `html` as you are already doing. Since you seem to be using `express` then it's pretty straight-forward.

app.js:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/imc')));
```

html:

```
<script src="/scripts/calculamc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! :) 

Where this "scripts" folder should be? Inside imc? And what's '__dirname' is for?

Comment: You don't need a `/scripts` folder. `/scripts` is a sort of variable that helps you export the path to your static asset. You should be fine with that code as is. The main concern is that your path may be wrong.